# Iterate over all EntityManager inside Stateful Bean

Tags: java, entitymanager

Is there a way to iterate over all listed EntityManager inside Stateful Bean?

```
@Stateful
@Local(SomeInterface.class)
public class ContextBean implements SomeInterface{

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="00")
    private EntityManager em00;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="01")
    private EntityManager em01;

    ...

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="0n")
    private EntityManager em0n;

    public ContextBean() {}

    public void test(){

       for(EntityManager em : ???){
         // Do something
       }

    }

}
```

Can I use loop and how please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you could iterate over each field, like this:

```
    Field[] fields = getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : fields) {
        if (field.getType().equals(EntityManager.class)) {
            EntityManager em = (EntityManager) field.get(this);
            // do something with em
        }
    }
```